# non-linear regression predictions goodness of fit

Tags: goodness-of-fit, nonlinear-regression, methodology

I have a non-linear model that, given some parameters and the initial state of the system can predict the outcome of this system after t times. I had train my model using some data and I'm now trying to check how good this model predict the outcome of other data.

However, I run into a methodological problem. My model behaves like a sigmoid curve, which means that after enough time, independently of the initial state, the system will be close to an asymptote. 
 My new data have initial states that are very different from each other. My observed data (the ones I'm now predicting) after some time t are now more similar (but still different).

My problem starts when I calculate r2 for my prediction vs observed data. If I compare the observed state to the predicted state my r2 e low (even negative) as the observed data is very close to each other and even small error's in my prediction will decrease my r2 a lot. On the other hand, if I compare observed change in state to predicted change in state I get a much better r2 (as the observed change is quite different for each point (very different starts, similar endings)).

I would like to know which one is the better calculation to do? And/or do you have other ideas? Or references I can read and check?

thanks in advance!!